# field line between two charged bodies?

Tags: electrostatics

Will all electric field lines from one charged body end on another charged body having same opposite charge?

And what if the charges are different?

Answer (score 1):

You can see the field line as the ideal path that a positively charged test particle would take, if placed motionless (with respect to the field source) in the field at a certain point.

You can immediately picture those lines for a single charge. See the pictures from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_line

In the situation with just one charge, you see that the electric field points outward if the charge is positive (as a test particle would be repelled), or inward if the charge is negative (as the test particle is attracted).

This is a general principle: negative charge -> line going in, positive charge -> line going out. This is by convention, as we take the test particle as positively charged.

With two bodies, the general principle holds: if the charges are different, the field line will start from the positive charge and go to the negative charge. If they are the same and positive, then you can have the situation in the picture of the Wikipedia article, with the test charge being repelled from the positive sources. With a little leap of immagination you can picture what happens with negative charges.

Answer (score 1):

*Will all electric field lines from one charged body end on another charged body having same opposite charge?*

In general no. They could for instance also end on two bodies, each having half of the opposite charge.

If you have two bodies of equal but opposite charge, all field lines from one body will end on the other body and there won't be any  other field lines.

If you have a net total charge, e.g if you have only one charged body or if you have two bodies with different charges, some field lines will end at infinity. This makes sense because the universe is charge neutral and if you wish you can include this compensating charge at infinity in your model.

All this is a consequence of Gauss's law which tells that the field lines through a closed surface (the flux) are related to the charge inside the surface.